# context isnt being read in the template

Tags: python, django

The `if statement` in the html code is not working at, all the likes are getting sent through the like button, but the button text isn't changing. I tried different ways of passing context but none of them are working.

The button is displayed as `like`, whether the post is liked or not, and the same is happening in the post list view.

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Blog
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class BlogsList(ListView):
    model=Blog
    template_name='blog/home.html'
    context_object_name='blogs'
    ordering=['-date_posted']




def like_post(request, blog_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked=False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked=True
    context={
    'is_liked':is_liked
    }   
    return HttpResponseRedirect(Blog.get_absolute_url(blog_id))

def post_detail(request, id):
    post=get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)

    context={
        'post':post,}
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',context)




def check_liked(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=blog_id)
    is_liked=False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.User.id).exists():
        is_liked=True
    else:
        is_liked=False
    context={
    'is_liked':is_liked
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html',context)
```

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse 

class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField()
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(blog_id):
        return reverse('post-detail',args=[str(blog_id)])
```

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns=[
path('',views.BlogsList.as_view(),name='blog-home'),
path('<int:blog_id>/like/', views.like_post, name='like_post'),
path('post/<int:id>/', views.post_detail, name='post-detail'),
]
```

**post_detail.html**:

```
<article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <h2>{{ post.author }}</h2>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if is_liked %}

                <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Unlike</button>

          {% else %}

                <button type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
          {% endif %}
        </form>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `is_liked` at the post detail as well.

```
def post_detail(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=id)
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists()
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```